# cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(*)) не возвращает нормальною строку

Tags: android, android-support-library

MediaMetadataCompat.getString не возвращает нормальною строку, если есть слова, отличные от английского языка:

```
MediaMetadataCompat compat = ...
Log.i(TAG, "test тест " + compat.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
```

> test тест Speeeedy EDM Blog - Ð³Ð»Ð°Ð²Ð½ÑÐ¹ Ð¸ÑÑÐ¾ÑÐ½Ð¸Ðº ÑÐ»ÐµÐºÑÑÐ¾Ð½Ð½Ð¾Ð¹ Ð¼ÑÐ·ÑÐºÐ¸ Ð²ÐºÐ¾Ð½ÑÐ°ÐºÑÐµ

should be:

> test тест Speeeedy EDM Blog - главный источник электронной музыки вконтакте

Пытаюсь получить метаданные о песни (певец, альбом, название и т.д.)

Соответственно проблемы тогда буду и не только с русскими словами, с японскими, арабскими и т.д.

Как тогда можно оптимизировать под все языки?

**update**

если точнее, то здесь я получая плохой результат:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
```

Comment: видимо кодировка не unicode (utf16).